# How to associate meaningful key with page id for Facebook Page Apps

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-page

We are creating a Facebook Page Tab app.  We want this to be installable on our customer's business Facebook Pages.  They will install this by visiting our SaaS app, where we have a specific customer id# for them.  From there they will have a button to "Add this App to your Facebook Page" button, which will use the JavaScript SDK's `FB.ui({method:"pagetab"...` call to add this to their page.

Now when one of their Facebook fans clicks into our customer's Page and then into our App, the App page gets sent the signed_request parameter which can be parsed to find their Page Id.

The trouble is that I cannot figure out a way to associate their customer id# with their Facebook Page Id.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this

```
      FB.ui(
        {
            method: 'pagetab'
        },
        function(response) {
            if (response != null && response.tabs_added != null) {

                $.each(response.tabs_added, function(pageid) {
                      alert(pageid);
                });
            }
        }
      );
```

Store the page ids by associating each with the customer id.

When a user comes to your app, you will get the page id. Then you can easily identify the customer id from page id.

Comment: Venu - I tried that technique but the callback was never called.  However, I just worked out why -- I was specifying a redirect_uri in the object parm of my FB.ui call, which would cause the page to reload and skip the callback.  But leaving that out, the callback does get called and so we are good to go!

Comment: You could avoid the ambigiuty of relying on the dialog callback by only adding the page tab via the API directly, having gotten manage_pages permission from the customer you can make an API call to install the tab directly: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs